# How to login to Azure Devops organization using non-microsoft account?

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I created an Azure Devops organization, added/invited a developer to the organization using his gmail address.

The problem is when he goes to the link, azure devops is asking for a microsoft account. But the developer has a gmail account. How do you proceed with logging in to Azure devops with a gmail account?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### If your Azure DevOps Account is Microsoft Account backed

Currently you don't. The user must create a profile at Microsoft. Using the following link the user can register one using their gmail email address so that they don't get a new email address etc:

```
https://signup.live.com/?lic=1
```

### If your Azure DevOps Account is Azure Active Directory backed

Azure active directory offers a number of options to invite users from [other profile providers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/b2b/google-federation). These federated accounts can be granted access to your Azure DevOps account.

Answer (score 2):

Azure devops service requires one to sign in with a microsoft account.

Any valid email address can be made to be a microsoft account. So you need to head to [microsoft account](https://account.microsoft.com/account) and provide the gmail address that you want to use with azure devops and create a microsoft account.

The password given here is only for this microsoft account and has got nothing to do with the gmail account.

Once you have created a microsoft account with the gmail address you can sign in with it on azure devops site.